# Can we use Truecaller SDK if truecaller isnt installed in device

Tags: java, android

If I try to use the following code, I am able to use Truecaller's SDK and fetch the user's profile if he has truecaller installed.

```
//has_truecaller = TrueSDK.getInstance().isUsable(); //doesnt work before init() methof
TrueSdkScope trueScope;
TrueSdkScope.Builder sdkBuilder = new TrueSdkScope.Builder(this, sdkCallback)
            .consentMode(TrueSdkScope.CONSENT_MODE_POPUP )
            .consentTitleOption( TrueSdkScope.SDK_CONSENT_TITLE_VERIFY )
            .footerType( TrueSdkScope.FOOTER_TYPE_SKIP );

if(has_truecaller) {
        trueScope = sdkBuilder.sdkOptions( TrueSdkScope.SDK_OPTION_WITH_OTP ).build();
}else{
        //TODO get mobile number
        BaseActivity.USER_MOBILE_NUMBER = "12345677";
        trueScope = sdkBuilder.sdkOptions( TrueSdkScope.SDK_OPTION_WITH_OTP ).build();
    }
TrueSDK.init(trueScope);
```

However If i remove Truecaller from the device i get the following error:

```
2-06 10:38:45.437 25694-25694/com.project.xyz.userclientapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.project.xyz.userclientapp, PID: 25694 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 Failed resolution of: Lretrofit2/converter/gson/GsonConverterFactory;
 at com.truecaller.android.sdk.b.c.a(Unknown Source:9)
 at com.truecaller.android.sdk.clients.a.<init>(Unknown Source:10)
 at com.truecaller.android.sdk.a.<init>(Unknown Source:46)
 at com.truecaller.android.sdk.a.a(Unknown Source:2)
 at com.truecaller.android.sdk.TrueSDK.init(Unknown Source:5)
 at com.project.xyz.userclientapp.login.LoginActivity.setupTrueSdk(LoginActivity.java:49)
 at com.project.xyz.userclientapp.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:30)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
 at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Could you clarify precisely what you're asking? Clearly here, the answer to the question in your title seems to be Yes, but what's the question you're asking after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the Truecaller app is present on the device or not by using the following line -
`TrueSDK.getInstance().isUsable()`

You do need to initialize the SDK using the init() method before checking for this. It will return a boolean true / false depending on wether Truecaller is installed or not.

Also, the logs what you shared are because of missing a library dependency in your android project. Can you try add the following dependency in your gradle. This should help solve the error -

`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'`

Comment: Yeah i missed the converter-gson dependency. Thanks

Comment: I want to know whether that truecaller profile is verified on truecaller or not..any idea how to fetch that? I’m unable to see any variable in TrueProfile corresponding to that..